# How would I close a frame and open another frame?

Tags: java, swing

I have a program so far where a frame pops up asking for a file location. If it can't find the file, it says "File not found", but if it does find the file, it says "file found". If it finds the file I also want to make the frame close and a new frame open up. I'm not sure how to do that though. Here's my code so far.

Panel class:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FilePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
private Reader reader;
private JTextField textField;
private JButton goButton;
private JLabel label;
private SpringLayout layout;

String fileLocation;
/**
 * Create the panel.
 */
public FilePanel() {

    textField = new JTextField();
    goButton = new JButton("Go!");
    label = new JLabel("Enter path to txt file.");
    layout = new SpringLayout();

    setupPanel();
} // end constructor 

private void setupPanel(){
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setLayout(layout);
    setSize(400,200);

    // Adds label 
    add(label);
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, label, 65, SpringLayout.NORTH, this);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, label, 125, SpringLayout.WEST, this);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, label, 81, SpringLayout.NORTH, this);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, label, -121, SpringLayout.EAST, this);

    // Adds text field
    add(textField);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, textField, 6, SpringLayout.SOUTH, label);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, textField, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, label);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, textField, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, label);

    // Adds button
    add(goButton);
    goButton.addActionListener(this);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, goButton, 6, SpringLayout.SOUTH, textField);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, goButton, 156, SpringLayout.WEST, this);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, goButton, 57, SpringLayout.SOUTH, textField);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, goButton, -151, SpringLayout.EAST, this);

}
// Action performed if the button 'Go!' button is pressed 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    try{
        fileLocation = textField.getText();

        textField.setText("");
        reader = new Reader(fileLocation);
        label.setText("File found!");

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e1){
        label.setText("File was not found");
    }
} // end actionPerformed



}
```

Here is my frame class:

```
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class FileWindow extends JFrame {

private FilePanel currentPanel;
private boolean close;
private JFrame frame;

public FileWindow(){

    currentPanel = new FilePanel();
    frame = new JFrame();

    setupFrame();
} // end constructor

private void setupFrame(){
    frame.setContentPane(currentPanel);
    frame.setSize(400,200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setTitle("File Scanner");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

} // end setupFrame

}
```

So basically in the try catch block in the panel class, I want to be able to set the frame to not visible, and then proceed to open up another frame. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using multiple JFrames, (It's bad practice) use a [Cardlayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Here is a simple example on how Cardlayouts work.

```
package main.frames;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame
{
static JPanel homeContainer;
static JPanel homePanel;
static JPanel otherPanel;
static CardLayout cl;

public MainFrame()
{
    JButton showOtherPanelBtn = new JButton("Show Other Panel");
    JButton backToHomeBtn = new JButton("Show Home Panel");

    cl = new CardLayout(5, 5);
    homeContainer = new JPanel(cl);
    homeContainer.setBackground(Color.black);

    homePanel = new JPanel();
    homePanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
    homePanel.add(showOtherPanelBtn);

    homeContainer.add(homePanel, "Home");

    otherPanel = new JPanel();
    otherPanel.setBackground(Color.green);
    otherPanel.add(backToHomeBtn);

    homeContainer.add(otherPanel, "Other Panel");

    showOtherPanelBtn.addActionListener(e -> cl.show(homeContainer, "Other Panel"));
    backToHomeBtn.addActionListener(e -> cl.show(homeContainer, "Home"));

    add(homeContainer);
    cl.show(homeContainer, "Home");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    setTitle("CardLayout Example");
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(MainFrame::new);
    }
}
```